# Unique Identification of a particular device type

Tags: webcam, fingerprint, wmi-query, wql

[Win32_PnPEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class has so many properties but I want to know that is there any property which identifies the **type of device** uniquely . For example I have a fingerprint scanner device and its device id is something like this "USB\VID_0A86" but as per my understanding it will be different for a device with different vendor.
I want to know the property whose value is same for all type of fingerprint scanners. Similarly same scenario for all webcams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, it is the ClassGuid :

[>>>>>check it here<<<<<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553426%28VS.85%29.aspx)